# Retrieve all functions that called by a user mode process in kernel mode debug including kernels functions

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg, callstack

I am trying to find all the functions including both user mode functions and kernel mode functions that `wmic.exe` calls to execute the `diskdrive` command. In order to do this I opened `wmic.exe` in my virtual machine and set breakpoint in kernel mode windbg on `WMIC!CParsedInfo::GetUser` and `WMIC!CExecEngine::ExecuteCommand`.
As soon as I input `diskdrive` debugger breaks on `ExecuteCommand`, I am in kernel mode through COM port, but I cant use `wt` command, however I can run instructions line by line and step in to every call and track all function in stack call, but this will take lots of time and it’s not optimized. Is there any way to do something similar to the `wt` command in the kernel debugger?

Whenever I use the `wt` command it outputs `^ Unimplemented error in 'wt'`.

Some extra info:

1. I am running Windows 11 Enterprise Build 22000.856 on VMWare and connected to it through the COM port for kernel debugging and the host OS is the latest version of Windows 11 Enterprise.
2. Windbg is also the latest version of windbg.
3. Both windbg and vmware running as administrator.
4. I am able to use all the usual commands I can see registers, see stack calls with single step, see threads and etc.
5. `wt` runs normally on my main OS for user mode processes on my main OS without any problem

Comment: What do you actually want? To find out the WMI query to use in your own wmic clone or get the same info without using WMI? If the latter, which specific info?

Comment: I am trying to find out where hard disks serial numbers are stored in kernel memory and then get them by my own driver directly when I find those addresses. I know those addresses are dynamic but as far as I have done reverse engineering I know that they only change if you restart WIndows (turning on/off does not have the same effect). But also I want to know how you retrieve all called functions. I read wt documentation and it seems most of the options are only for User mode. Why is that? Why can I do single step and trace stack call, but not use wt?! Should I use script?

Comment: Serial number might be DeviceIOControl...